# date not ordering correctly on axis in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get the data to be in chronological order on the x-axis and have been struggling. The x-axis data (survey_date) I believe is in the correct format.

```
t4 <- structure(list(survey_date = structure(c(15034, 15413, 15761, 
15762, 16120, 16490, 16854, 16855, 17225, 17959), class = "Date"), 
    avg_count = c(336, 388, 375.4, 370, 225, 131, 282, 329, 148, 
    30.66666667)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

p <- ggplot() + geom_bar(data = t4, aes(x=survey_date,y=avg_count),stat = "identity")
p
```

[image]

Comment: You are looking for bar plot, but the survey_date is single observation

Comment: i.e. do you want something like `t4 %>% group_by(year = year(survey_date)) %>% summarise(avg_count = sum(avg_count)) %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x= year,y=avg_count),stat = "identity")`

Comment: I would like a bar for each observation with the date of the observation as a label on the x-axis.

Comment: The problem is that the "bar" for a day is so small with such a large date range. If you use points, you can see the data: `ggplot(t4) + aes(x=survey_date,y=avg_count) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is somewhat irregularly spaced, so ggplot is inferring that the resolution of x axis should be daily, making each bar only one day wide.

Since you **generally** have only have one observation per year, it might be simplest to use the year as your x axis. This will keep even spacing of years, but it unfortunately obscures the lower values when there are multiple in a year. I've made the bars slightly transparent to show this.

```
ggplot(data = t4, aes(x=lubridate::year(survey_date),y=avg_count)) + 
  geom_col(position = "identity", alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1), name = NULL)
```

[image]

Or you might show each date on a discrete axis. Note that I'm converting the text created by `format()` into a sorted factor using `forcats::fct_reorder`, otherwise it would show up alphabetically, which in this date format is not chronological.

```
ggplot() + geom_col(data = t4, 
                    aes(x=format(survey_date, "%m/%d/%y") %>% forcats::fct_reorder(survey_date),
                        y=avg_count)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL)
```

[image]

Or you might aggregate the data annually first:

```
library(dplyr)
t4 %>%
  group_by(year = lubridate::year(survey_date)) %>%
  summarize(avg_count = mean(avg_count)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, avg_count)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1), name = NULL)
```

[image]

Or another variation, putting year into facets:

```
t4 %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(survey_date),
         survey_date2 = format(survey_date, "%m/%d") %>% 
           forcats::fct_reorder(survey_date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(survey_date2, avg_count)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~year, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with geom_bar() is that your plot's x axis is so wide that the "bar" is almost invisible.
You ahve two options:

## 1. Increase the bar's width manually:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_bar(data = t4, 
 aes(x=survey_date,y=avg_count),
 stat = "identity", width = 10)
```

[image]

## 2. Use `geom_segment()` and R will automatically set a visible width.

```
ggplot(data = t4, aes(x = survey_date, y = avg_count)) + 
geom_segment(aes(xend = survey_date, yend = 0))
```

[image]